# Deciphering a number system

Tags: mathematics, pattern

If I were to say that:

```
2    +   2   =   22
2    +   q   =   q2
q    +   2   =   q2
22   +   q2  =   q22
2q2  +   q   =   q2q
qqq  +   22  =   qq22

2    x   2   =   22
2    x   q   =   2q
q    x   2   =   2q
2q   x   q   =   2q22
q2q  x   q2  =   q22222
qq   x   qq  =   q222q
```

could you then tell me what    `2qq2  x   qq2` is?

Some notes:

- the '`x`' in the above is ordinary mathematical multiplication, the '`+`' is addition, and the '`=`' is equality.
- each string of `2`'s and `q`'s is a natural number. Every string is a number, and every number except 0 is a string (including the empty string).
- you do not need every piece of information in the box to determine an answer, though the answer will be consistent with every piece of information in the box.

---

Since someone got a correct answer, using different reasoning than I did, I'll add my own reasoning below for those who are interested:

> First off, the empty string is 1. If some string `x` corresponds to some integer $n$, then `2x` corresponds to $2n$ and `qx` corresponds to $2n + 1$. So `2` = $2 \times 1$ = $2$, `q` = $2 \times 1 + 1$ = $3$ and so on. `qq2` = $2 \times (2 \times 2 + 1) + 1$ = 11, and `2qq2` thus = $2 \times 11$ = $22$, the product of which is $242$ = $2 \times (2 \times (2 \times (2 \times (2 \times (2 \times (2 + 1) + 1) + 1))) + 1)$ = `2q22qqq`.

Comment: Would you like to tell us whether every natural number is representable by some string of `2`s and `q`s? (Feel free not to.)

Comment: Indeed every natural number is representable, if you include the empty string and don't include 0 as a natural number. My apologies for the omission, that one slipped past me.

Comment: At the risk of being petty and/or splitting hairs: if, as you say, '`+`' and '`x`' are ordinary addition and multiplication, then $a+b=b+a$ and $a\times b=b\times a$ for all $a$ and $b$, so you didn't really need to tell us that $2+q=q+2$ and $2\times q=q\times 2$ — or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I don't think you are misunderstanding anything. I put those in for clarity's sake, and to demonstrate that there aren't different 'rules' for translating strings based just on their position in the line. Perhaps unnecessary, but a bit of redundancy never hurt anyone.

Comment: OK. Are you sure $\rm 2q2+q=q22q$? I've got a decipherment that works for every line except that one.

Comment: @PeregrineRook You're absolutely right. That should be equal to `q2q`. Will correct in a moment. Feel like an idiot for missing that one...

Comment: Your system is exactly equivalent to @PeregrineRook's system, just expressed in a different way.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Thanks for pointing that out.  I was considering the option of saying it, but I didn’t want to be argumentative. … … … … … … … … … You’ve probably seen the tee-shirt: “There are 10 kinds of people in the world — those who understand binary and those who don’t.”  It occurred to me that my exposition is more straightforward for people who understand binary, and the OP’s might be more accessible to those who don’t, so there’s a place for both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is

> `2q22qqq`

The system:

> Replace `2` with $0$ and `q` with $1$. 
> Add another $1$ at the end, then reverse the order of the string of bits
> and interpret it as a binary integer. 
> For example,
> `2   =` $\phantom{00}10 = \phantom{0}2$
> `22  =` $\phantom{0}100 = \phantom{0}4$
> `222 =` $1000 = \phantom{0}8$, etc.
> `q   =` $\phantom{00}11 = \phantom{0}3$
> `qq  =` $\phantom{0}111 = \phantom{0}7$
> `qqq =` $1111 = 15$, etc.
> `q2  =` $\phantom{0}101 = \phantom{0}5$
> `2q  =` $\phantom{0}110 = \phantom{0}6$, and so on.

How I determined this answer:

> Given that we are talking about ordinary addition and multiplication,
> and only the numbers are enciphered, I can say that, for any `a`, 
> `a+a =`$2~\times$`a`, `a+a+a=` $3~\times$`a`, `a+a+a+a =`$4~\times$`a`, etc. 
> So `2+2` equals $2~\times$`2`. 
> But `2+2 = 2×2`, so `2` equals $2$.
>
> `2+2 = 2×2 = 22`, so `22` equals $4$.
> `q ≠`$0$, because if `q =`$0$, then `2+q`
> (which equals `q+2` by the commutative property of addition) would equal `2`. 
> (Also, the OP suggested that $0$ was not representable.) 
> `q ≠`$1$, because if `q =`$1$, then `2×q`
> (which equals `q×2` by the commutative property of multiplication)
> would equal `2`. 
> I interpreted the OP’s comment that
> “every natural number is representable” to mean
> “every natural number is representable ***uniquely***”,
> so `q ≠ 2`($2$) and `q ≠`$4$. 
> I guessed that maybe `q` was $3$,
> which led to the conclusion that `2+q =` $2+3=5$,
> so `q2` must be $5$, and `2×q =` $2\times 3=6$, so `2q` must be $6$. 
> So, I had
> `2   =` $2$
> `q   =` $3$
> `22  =` $4$
> `q2  =` $5$
> `2q  =` $6$
> (some of which were guesses). 
> Between that,
> and the OP’s hint that some number might be representable as an empty string,
> I guessed the rest. 
> All the given equations are (now) consistent with this scheme.

## The specific question:

> `2qq2 =` $10110 = 22$
> `qq2  =` $\phantom{0}1011 = 11$
>
> Working in binary:\begin{align}10110\\\times\qquad 1011\\\hline10110\\10110\phantom{0}\\+~~10110\phantom{000}\\\hline11110010\end{align}
> Working in decimal:
> $22 \times 11 = 242 = 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 2 = 11110010_2$
>
> Either way, strip off the leading $1$ and reverse the remaining bits
> to get $0100111 \leftrightarrow$ `2q22qqq`.

Comment: Your explanation does work, though It's not what I originally thought of (which I may add to the question in a spoiler later) but your answer to the specific question is incorrect. Take a look at the first line of your last spoiler block...

Comment: There you go! Accepted, and edit to question explaining my own reasoning coming shortly.

Comment: Sigh; nobody's perfect.     :-)     Thanks for the nudge.